# jquery html disappears on click event

Tags: jquery

Please see the following code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <button id="helloButton">
        Search</button>
    <div id="hello">


    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
        function () {

            $('#helloButton').click(function () {


                $('#hello').html('<div>hello world</div>');

            });

        });
    </script>
</div>
</form>
```

When I use this script, all it does is flash "hello world", it doesn't keep it on the page. Does this has something to do with the click event? I'm trying to click the button and then leave the  object on the page.

Comment: I copy-pasted your codes [here](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/QD7gq/) and I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: @reigel you did not paste the form tag, that's why it does not submit in jsfiddle

Comment: @amosrivera - ahh yeah! silly me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Otherwise you can simply do a return false which will do both
preventDefault and stop propagation

```
$('#helloButton').click(function (e) {

    $('#hello').html('<div>hello world</div>');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: should that return be at the end of the function?

Comment: anything after return false; will not reach and will not run

Comment: @cfram54 , thanks for editing , i forgot ...i was on vacation till today and lost touch with coding....i am getting warmed up

Answer (score 4):

in order to prevent the form from posting, so that you can see your changes, you need to call [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$('#helloButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#hello').html('<div>hello world</div>');
});
```